# How to make the contents in left side bar collapsible

Tags: python, interface, jupyter-lab

Currently I am trying to figure out how to change the setting for the left sidebar for jupyterlab.

When I press the folder, it automatically changes the directory and shows what is in the folder. (for example, if I have a folder name `my_modules` and press it from the sidebar, then left sidebar shows what is only in that directory)

But instead if I want to see what is in the directory as collapsible list. That is when I press the directory icon, folder uncollapses and shows the contents of the folder underneath the icon. How would I do that?

Comment: Hi Young. Stack Overflow is meant for code specific questions. Consider asking your question on Super User: https://superuser.com/